# ビットの深さに応じて処理を振り分けたい

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pillow

`PIL`と`numpy`を使用してイメージの配列を取得しています。
その情報を、`QImage`のコンストラクタに渡して、`Image`オブジェクトをこさえています。
その時、`QImage`のコンストラクタの第五引数に対して、フォーマットの情報を渡します。
例えば、`24bit`の画像に対しては、`QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888`を渡します。
変換の目安としては、PILの場合、"L"が８bitを、”RGB"が`24bit`を、"RGBA"が`32bit`を表わし、`mode`を取得して、"L"か"RGB"か、"RGBA"かで適用するフォーマットを分けていました。

```
    #filenameはimageの名前あるいはディレクトリ
    im = Image.open(filename)
    print(im.mode)
    data = np.array(im)
    if im.mode == "RGB":            
        qimagein = QtGui.QImage(data.data, data.shape[1], data.shape[0], data.strides[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
    elif im.mode == "RGBA":
        qimagein = QtGui.QImage(data.data, data.shape[1], data.shape[0], data.strides[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)
    elif im.mode == "1":
        qimagein = QtGui.QImage(data.data, data.shape[1], data.shape[0], data.strides[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_Mono)
    elif im.mode == "L":
        qimagein = QtGui.QImage(data.data, data.shape[1], data.shape[0], data.strides[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_Indexed8)
    elif im.mode == "P":
        qimagein = QtGui.QImage(data.data, data.shape[1], data.shape[0], data.strides[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_Indexed8)
```

この時、PというModeが帰って来たものですから、[Pillowのチートシート](https://qiita.com/pashango2/items/145d858eff3c505c100a)で確認したところ、
`8bit`だけれども、パレットモードだということです。
これがオリジナルの8bitのイメージなのですけれども、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
上記の処理に載せた後に、イメージを描画すると、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
こんな感じでモノクロになります。
`8`ビットを描画するために指定するフォーマットとしては、
`Format_Indexed8`くらいしかなさそうなんですけれども、
あきらめるしかないでしょうか？
[PySide QImage](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QImage.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QImage.convertToFormat)
Pillowの公式サイトで、PillowはQt系のImageコンストラクタの処理と連携しており、
"1","L","P","RGB","RGBA"の5つのモードには対応している。
これ以外のモードを扱うには、`convert`を行えと書いてあるのですが、
"P"も対応しているようです。しかし、肝心の、どのフォーマットに当てはめればいいのかが
わかりません。
"RGB"の場合は問題ないのですが、"RGBA"の場合だと、若干色が変化することもあります。

例えば、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
が、RGBAとして割り振られたコードを追加した後だと、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
こんな風に、一部の色が完全に違うものになってしまいます。
これはどうしてなのかも知りたいです。
[Pillow ImageQt Module](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/ImageQt.html?highlight=convert)

1．8bitのパレットモードの画像を、オリジナルと同様に表示する方法
2．RGBAの場合に色が変化する原因と、対処法

Comment: 2については、既に解決いたしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QImage`生成時に指定するフォーマットは「`QtGui.QImage.Format_Indexed8`」でよいと思います。(質問文で挙げられているPNGファイルで直接`QImage`を生成すると`format()`メソッドは`QtGui.QImage.Format_Indexed8`を返すので)

ただし、8bitフォーマットの場合、「`setColorTable()`」でカラーテーブル(パレット)を設定する必要があるようです。
ですので、Pillowで生成したイメージデータからパレットデータを取得して(`im.getpalette()`)、生成した`QImage`データに`setColorTable()`で設定すれば、期待通りの色で表示されると思います。

---

追記(訂正あり)
RGB形式のPNGファイルについて、`im.getpalette()`で取得できるのは、`R,G,B`の値が並んだ配列と思います。

```
R0,G0,B0,R1,G1,B1, ... ,Rn,Gn,Bn
(0...nはパレットのインデクス)
```

一方、`QImage.setColorTable()`で指定するのは`RRGGBB`の整数値の配列と思います。
なので、変換して設定する必要があるかと思います。

＃アルファ値は255として、以下のように計算すればよいです。

```
255 * 0x1000000 + R値 * 0x10000 + G値 * 0x100 + B値
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。言われたとおりにしてみたのですが、今度は何も映らなくなってしまいました。しかし、`setColorTable()`に入れこんだ後、`print`文で出力してみると、確かにそのテーブルデータは入っているようです。なぜ反映されないのかは当然ながら不明です。`palette=im.getpalette()`で取得したものを、`qimagein.setColorTable(palette)`としています。

Comment: なるほど。RRGGBBの整数値なんですね。変換の仕方がわかりませんが、調べてみます。その他、2番目の疑問であるRGBAだと色が変化するのは、RGB→BGR変換が必要なのだということが、リンク先(PILチートシートより判明しました。)これは、所定の手続きに従ったところ、改善しました。

Comment: すいません。paletteの値は、整数値リストでした。`[0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 10, 8, 9, 7, 26, 0, 8, 22, 0, 8, 20, 19, 0, 28, 27, 0, 20, 22, 27, 11, 16, 26, 32, 30, 0, 42, 39, 0, 59, 56, 2, 20, 26, 43, 12, 16, 36, 34, 42, 62, 61, 68, 47, 76, 71, 0, 84, 78, 0, 92, 86, 0, 76, 73, 28, 89, 86, 20, 80, 78, 28, 100, 94, 5, 99, 93, 18, 104, 99, 4, 116, 105, 9, 104,...........]`でした。